# Create a custom popup that is responsive and can post to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, popup

I am currently working on an intranet solution for my company written in PHP using the Laravel framework, this requires me to do a lot of new things I have never done before, 1 of these is creating a popup that has dynamic html depending on a drop down list such as this:

I have a calendar (http://fullcalendar.io/)
[image]
When I click on a day in this calendar a popup should show that looks something like this: [image]

After selecting a value from that dropdown list a different set of fields should be shown depending on the value selected for example:[image]
OR
[image]
So I really need a lot of control over the popup, I have no previous experience with working with popups (unless a simple alert of a variable in javascript counts) and I need a whole deal of functionality, it also needs to be able to post to a database so I think it might even have to be a form element. I also need to be able to fire the popup from the onclick event from the fields in my calendar so that makes it extra hard for someone who has always written back end code up until now.

SO WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION?
Could anyone tell me what the easiest/fastest way to achieve this is without losing any functionality necessities, can I do this from php, does a feature like this exist in the Laravel framework?(if it does I coudldn't find it) or do I have to start using something like jquery?

I found a bunch of libraries such as Fancybox that claim to be able to do this but I can't make head nor tail out of their usage guide.

For everyone who thinks this doesn't belong here: my only question is not "Is it Possible?" I am also asking how do I do it, what do I write in my html, javascript, php to make it work?

EDIT: I just read something about jquery dialogs that seems interesting, seems like you can use jquery dialogs to create a popup from a form you have in your html (form is hidden) but I can't seem to get the code to fire off the popup (dialog) to work so far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({        
        //calendar options here        
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            //to get date use date.format());
            //POPUPCODE START
            $("#logform").dialog({                                                            //Shows dialog
                height: 250,
                width: 450,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Save": function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/url/to/submit",                   //
                            timeout: 30000,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $('#modalform').serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
                                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
                            },
                            success: function(data){                                                        
                                 //Do stuff here on success such as modal info      
                                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }),    
            //POPUPCODE END
            var myCalendar = $('#calendar'); 
            myCalendar.fullCalendar();
            var myEvent = {
                title:"Work 7.6h",
                allDay: true,
                start: date,
                end: date
            };

            myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent,true );

        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            var myCalendar = $('#calendar'); 
            myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent._id);

        }    
    })

});
```

And for my html I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Calendar</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                                        <a class='iframe' href='home.blade.php'>Click me</a>
                </div>
                                <form id="logform" style="display:none">
                                    <input type="text" name="something">
                                    <input type="text" name="somethingelse">
                                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The trouble started only after adding the code between //popupcode start and //popupcode end now my calendar won't even show and I get

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The place it is pointing at is the 3rd line above my //popupcode end here:

```
}
                        }
                    }   //this one
                }
            }),    
            //POPUPCODE END
```

But no matter what I add or remove there I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, instead of making things harder by learning all kinds of new things I got it to work by removing all the code I added previously and adding 1 line of code to create the popup by using jquery.

I removed all the code that I was using to create the popup and replaced it by this: `$("#somediv").load().dialog({modal:true});`

I created a div called 'somediv' around my form and now it's doing what I need it to do, seeing as my entire form is in the popup now I'm pretty sure I can add a button to it that can submit the form so I can catch that with php and then I'll be able to do whatever I want with the data in php (post to database or return error messages etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, i recommend to use Javascript.

It's possible with only PHP, HTML and CSS but you will have to refresh the page all the time for the next popup to appear.

You can just make divs that are positioned fixed or absolute and they will overlay the underlaying content. The overlaying div(popup) will be a normal div where you can make forms and whatever you want.
Here is a quick jsfiddle I threw toghether: 
http://jsfiddle.net/0zvqm5nr/17/

Here is the code:

HTML

```
 <div class="calendar">
    <h1>Your calendar would be here</h1>
    <button id="popupButton">13.05.2015</button>
</div>
<div class="popup">
    <h2>13.05.2015</h2>
    Activity: 
    <form action="site.php" method="post">
        <select id="activity">
            <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Select</option>
            <option>work</option>
            <option>youth leave</option>
        </select>
    </form> 
</div>
<div class="popup">
    <h3>Work 13.05.2015</h3>
    this will be the work popup
</div>
<div class="popup">
    <h3>Youth leave 13.05.2015</h3>
    this will be the youth leave popup
</div>
```

CSS

```
.calendar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}
.popup {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("popupButton").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.display = "block"    
}
document.getElementById("activity").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.display = "none" 
   var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    if (selectedValue == "work") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[1].style.display = "block";       
    }
    if (selectedValue == "youth leave") {
         document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[2].style.display = "block";       
    }
}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: is there a way to make the popup as small as possible (height wise) considering the content, like you would have something called wrap_content or something (i'm using jsfiddle to test this out and it doesn't really do what i need it to do) It's quite close but not entirely what I need, also I still don't know how to use this to do a post, can I just place the different div's inside the form and do a submit of all of them?

Comment: Also I see that the popup gets overwritten when i change my value in dropdown but I need it to append (so people can also change dropdown afterwards if they make a mistake)

Comment: this is just a normal HTML div. In the CSS you can change the height and width values so it fits your needs or you can make a wrap around it and set height and width to 100%.

Comment: About the set of fields that must be shown, you can do this in javascript. Its the same as the popup. Make HTML divs(in the dropdown) for the set of fields and set it to display: none. Get the value of the dropdown and then show the set of fields you need for the selected option in the dropdown.

Comment: Yeah that was the part I was figuring out just now, I got the popup to work, I have a dropdown and now I also have some fields that are dynamically showing and hiding depending on my dropdown, now I just need to connect it to my database using PHP and I'm done